# проблемы с кодировкой при выводе результатов пинга через php

Tags: php, windows, кодировка, cmd, exec

Использую код

```
exec ('ping ya.ru',$cmd);
$row= count ($cmd);
$res="";
for ($i=0; $i<=$row; $i++)
{
$res = $res. "\n". $cmd[$i];
};

echo $res;
```

Кодировка скрипта UTF-8. Результат имею следующий http://prntscr.com/n93rva

Comment: кодировка консоли зато не утф

Comment: А можно так по-быстрому "починить" вывод от пинга - `exec("env LC_ALL=C ping ya.ru", $cmd);`

Comment: вот результат array(0) { } от модификации кода exec("env LC_ALL=C ping ya.ru", $cmd);

Comment: @ВладимирАфанасьев cорри ((( не увидел тег `windows`

Comment: можно воспользоваться,  для перекодировки, функцией [iconv()](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.iconv.php), если у вас установлено расширение iconv.